# PHP Swagger - path at area level

Tags: php, swagger, nelmioapidocbundle

How do I specify paths at the area level?

Currently I have this:

```
paths:
      /internal_api/token/refresh:
        post:
          tags:
            - Auth
...
areas:
      default:
          path_patterns: 
              - ^/api(?!/doc$)(?!/doc/)(?!/.+/audit/) 
      internal:
          path_patterns: 
              - ^/internal\_api(?!/doc$)(?!/.+/audit/)
```

I don't want the refresh token path appear for public api docs.
Tried to move path under area but it didn't work.

I tried moved a path under area but got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add documentation fields per area:

```yaml
nelmio_api_doc:
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: 
                - ^/api(?!/doc$)(?!/doc/)(?!/.+/audit/) 
        internal:
           documentation:
               paths:
                   /internal_api/token/refresh:
                       post:
                            tags:
                                 - Auth

           path_patterns: 
                - ^/internal\_api(?!/doc$)(?!/.+/audit/)
```